# How to develop Multistage classification model using deep learning

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks, classification

I am little confused while doing multistage classification using deep learning model.

I have data as below:

```
1st stage classification: 
Living Things---> Animals/ Birds/ mammals

2nd stage classification:

Animals---> Dog/Cat/Horse/Rabbit/Panda
Birds---> Peacock, Parrot, Dove, Sparrow
Mammals--->Whale, Humans, Goats, Bats, Elephant
```

So, First I have to classify my images into 3 different categories, after that in next stage, I have to classify the output of those 3 into 14 different class.

I don't know how to this multi stage classification. If anyone have idea please suggest.

Comment: If you trained the model with the last stage labels, it would be straightforward to track the initial/intermediate stages since it would be analogous to tracing the root of a tree

Comment: Thank you for response, but I want to classify generallized way on basis of their groups first and then into specific classes.

Comment: The category Animals encompasses both Birds and Mammals

Comment: You have not described a reason why the concept of "first stage/second stage" needs to be a part of training. Instead, you can incorporate this logic as part of how the model is interpreted after giving predictions. Just train the model with 2 sets of output nodes: one for "living things" and one for all of the other categories.